# Why use Yeshua instead of Jesus?

Tags: language, name-of-jesus, hebrew

We known the name of Christ through the Bible which is written in κοινή greek. In the original language the name is Ἰησοῦς which transliterated to Latin as Iesus and then to English as Jesus.

**Why then do some Christians feel a need to Judaism the name and return it to Modern Hebrew יֵשׁוּעַ (Yeshua)?** Taking in consideration that Modern Hebrew is not the same as the Hebrew used at the time of Christ and that Modern Hebrew was invented in the XIX century.

To clarify my concern I will cite from a book of John Owen about the subject

> They said Jesus was anathema, or "one accursed." They looked at him as a person to be detested and abominated as the common odium of their gods and men. Hence, at his mention they used to say, "Jesus anathema." He is, or let him be, "accursed, detested, destroyed." And the Jews continue in this blasphemy to this day, hiding their cursed sentiments under a corrupt pronunciation of his name. For instead of Yeshua, they write and call him
>   Yeshu (ישו), the initial letters of yimmach shemo vezikhro — that is, "Let his name and memory be blotted out;" the same as "Jesus anathema." And this
>   blasphemy of pronouncing Jesus accursed was what the first persecutors of the
>   church tested the faith of Christians with, as Pliny said in his epistle to Trajan;Justin Martyr with other apologists agree. *(On the Holy Spirit (Pneumatologia) by John Owen - Book 1 Chapter 1)*

Also according to Stanley Porter, in “Did Jesus Ever Teach In Greek?” (Tyndale Bulletin 44, no. 1 [1993]: 199–235) in Israel many Jews including Jesus spoke Greek.

In John 19:20 the name of Ἰησοῦς and Iesus is used in front of the crowd

> [John 19:20] Then many of the Jews read this title, for the place where Jesus was crucified was near the city; and it was written in Hebrew, Greek, and Latin.

Comment: My point with the mention of the languages was to restrain the argument that Yeshua is a more faithful rendition of the name of Christ, given the fact that they do not spoke only Hebrew

Comment: Alrighty, I'll remove that comment.

Comment: This question is related, but the answers don't really get at *why* people feel this need: [What is the Biblical basis for using the names “Yeshua” and “Yehoshua” (Joshua) for Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46238/6071)

Comment: Hmm, *why* do Christians think names are important? At least, the names we use for God and Jesus? Well, names, as a topic, is complicated and has a lot of history. Most of it boils down to inheriting that almost occult belief that spirits listen better when you get their name right and say it lots of times, contrasted with the enshrined belief (the 3rd commandment) that saying a spirit's name when you don't mean it is offensive and brings that spirit's wrath. *Reasons* these days are mostly along the lines "well, don't you want to say it right? Don't you want to say it the way Jesus said it?"

Comment: **Why then do some Christians feel a need to Judaize the name and return it to Modern Hebrew יֵשׁוּעַ (Yeshua)?** Pronouncing the name of Jesus in Hebrew or Aramaic is not Judaizing Our Lord’s name. It is using a valid Sacred Biblical language with devotion. We are not of the Jewish nation, we are Christians.

Comment: Can you provide a link that states that some **Christians feel a need to Judaize the name and return it to Modern Hebrew יֵשׁוּעַ (Yeshua)?**

Comment: Modern non-Christian Jews don’t call him Yeshua but Yeshu. The quote you included only strengthens the argument FOR Yeshua. Yeshua means savior reason why the a is dropped to deny him as the savior for those who reject ‘Christ’ianity. My name in different languages sounds different but if someone is intimately close to me and calls me by my name in my mother tongue with the mother tongue accent and dialect they will very likely get my attention instantly because few people know my name in that way.

Answer (score 3):

**Why use Yeshua instead of Jesus?**

Besides the simplest and most obvious reason for doing so is because we can, I will give you the reason why I do this myself when I am alone and not hindered by being overheard by others. But I will say this much. One of the reasons I do it is because of devotion to the name of Jesus. Now let me explain where I am going with this from time to time.

The claim that modern Hebrew (or Aramaic) is not the same as the Hebrew (or Aramaic) used at the time of Christ for the Hebraic name of Jesus remains simply on a theoretical level. Some dispute that claim.

> Some of rabbinical sources comment on the reasons for the missing ayin from Yeshu, as opposed to the Hebrew Bible Yeshua and Yehoshuah... A tradition states that the shortening to Yeshu relates to the Y-SH-U of the yimach shemo "may his name be obliterated.” Against this David Flusser suggested that the name Yeshu itself was "in no way abusive," but "almost certainly" a Galilean dialect form of Yeshua. But E.Y. Kutscher showed that the `ayin was still pronounced in Galilee, refuting a thesis by Paul Kahle. - [Yeshua](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshua)

**Those who employ the name of Jesus in either Aramaic or Hebrew are not Judaizing the name of Our Lord, but pronouncing his Holy Name as such in devotional manner or in a Christian Rite that frequently employs either Hebrew or Aramaic in their liturgies.**

Being a Catholic of the Latin Rite and greatly influenced by the Church’s traditions, I will explain my own motivation based on such.

The Catholic Maronite Rite uses Aramaic (Syriac) as a liturgical language and the name of Jesus in their Rite is **Yeshua**. I occasionally worship in this Eastern Catholic Rite.

Many of us can recall Mel Gibson’s movie [***The Passion of the Christ***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passion_of_the_Christ) in which all the dialogues were done in the languages employed at the time of Our Lord.

When I first watched this movie I decided to ask a friend who has a minor in biblical languages if he could recite in Aramaic the Our Father, the Ave Maria, the Gloria Patri along with the phrase begone Satan on a CD. The reason was that I could say the rosary in Aramaic, the language which Our Lord spoke. It is a purely devotional aspect that I have incorporated into my prayer life. What more needs to be said?

There are many other factors that one can incorporate into this response, such as:

- The Catholic Church acknowledges Latin, Greek, Hebrew and Aramaic (also known as liturgical Syriac) as being  [sacred languages](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/liturgy/details/ns_lit_doc_20110209_lingua_en.html).
- Our Lord spoke the common language (Aramaic) of the people in his day and age, but recited Hebrew in the synagogue when he read Sacred Scripture out loud.
- Pope Pius XII allowed the use of [Hebrew in the Tridentine Mass](https://jewinthepew.org/2015/02/11/11-february-bruno-hussar-founds-the-work-of-st-james-neve-shalom-1955-and-issues-statutes-of-the-association-1956/) for Catholics living in Israel for obvious reasons. (Sorry folks, Latin was not the only language employed at Mass prior to the Second Vatican Council in the Roman Rite.)
- The Maronite Catholic Rite may employ either Aramaic (Syriac) or Arabic in their liturgy, but the words of consecration must be in Aramaic, the very language Christ spoke at the Last Supper.

Although pronouncing the name of Jesus in any particular language has much merit. Pronouncing it in either Hebrew or Aramaic adds something special in my mind. How many times did Our Lord heard his most holy Mother Mary call him affectionately by his name: [Yeshua](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/liturgy/details/ns_lit_doc_20110209_lingua_en.html).

Here are some YouTube video examples (dialect may very):

- [Shlomlech Ave Maria Hail Mary in Aramaic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYBQu8OY_b8&app=desktop)
- [Shlom Lech Maryam (Hail Mary) in Aramaic with Arabic,and English script ماجدة الرومي](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uesa0fO3fcg&list=PL7rAZVeP2-7W7I4ImNtEfpsKDyhxVX506&app=desktop)
- [Lord's Prayer (Aramaic)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROM5EpCQUlg&t=102s&app=desktop)
- [Abun d'bashmayo (Aramaic) The Lord's prayer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqLZr11JhMM&app=desktop)
- [Musical Aramaic rendition of the Our Father that moved the pope in Georgia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=locW-9S00VU&app=desktop)
- [The Words of Consecration in the Maronite Mass الكلام الجوهريّ في القدّاس المارونيّ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD8Gno7-kGo&app=desktop)
- [Maronite Words of Consecration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e-SdmpSvs0&app=desktop)

Whether or not we pronounce the name of Jesus as Yeshua or not is unimportant to most, but for some it brings us closer to the historical Christ in his day and age, in a loving traditional way of speaking.

Holy is the name of [Jesus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_(name)) **ישועה "yeshua"** forever in Hebrew or Aramaic forever!

**Addendum:**

> **East Syriac Ishoʕ**
>
> Yeshuuʕ or Ishoʕ, the Syriac name of Jesus
> Aramaic and Classical Syriac render the pronunciation of the same letters as ܝܫܘܥ yeshuuʕ (yešuʕ) /yeʃuʕ/ and ܝܫܘܥ ishoʕ (išoʕ) /iʃoʕ/. The Aramaic Bibles and the Peshitta Syriac preserve these same spellings. Current scholarly consensus posits that the NT texts were translated from the Greek, but this theory is not supported directly at least by the name for Jesus, which is not a simple transliteration of the Greek form as would otherwise be expected, as Greek did not have an "sh" [ʃ] sound, and substituted [s]; and likewise lacked and therefore omitted the final ‘ayin sound [ʕ]. Moreover, Eusebius (early fourth century) reports that Papius (early second century) reports that Jesus's disciple Matthew wrote a gospel "in the Hebrew language". **(Note: Scholars typically argue the word "Hebrew" in the New Testament refers to Aramaic; however, others have attempted to refute this view.)** The Aramaic of the Peshitta does not distinguish between Joshua and Jesus, and the Lexicon of William Jennings gives the same form ܝܫܘܥ for both names. The Hebrew final letter ayin ע is equivalent to final ܥ in Classical Syriac and East Syriac and West Syriac. **It can be argued that the Aramaic speakers who used this name had a continual connection to the Aramaic-speakers in communities founded by the apostles and other students of Jesus, thus independently preserved his historical name Yeshuuʕ and the Eastern dialectical Ishoʕ.** Those churches following the East Syriac Rite still preserve the name Ishoʕ. - [Yeshua (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshua)

Other articles of interest may be read if desired:

- [In which language did Pontius Pilate communicate with Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/56460/25495)
- [What language did Jesus speak?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/what-language-did-jesus-speak/73876#73876)
- [What language did Jesus speak? The pope and Israel’s prime minister disagree.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2014/05/27/what-language-did-jesus-speak-the-pope-and-israels-prime-minister-disagree/)

Answer (score 2):

The "J" in Biblical names translated to English are usually "׳" (yod) in Hebrew, pronounced as "i".

For example,

- Jesus -  ישוע "yeshua"
- John -  יוחנן "yokhanan"
- Joshua - יהושע "yohushua"
- Joseph - יוסף "yosef"
- L-RD - יהוה "YHWH"

Furthermore, **ישועה** "**yeshua**" means **salvation**, pronounced the same as **ישוע** (**Jesus**).

For more interesting Biblical name translations into Chinese, you are welcome to visit my other post: [Did early Chinese Protestant actually call God “(old) Gentleman of Fiery Magnificence”, as Wikipedia says?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/73964/47007)

Many Christian who choose to use Yeshua instead of Jesus like the significant meaning of salvation behind the Hebrew word; many are also fans of Hebrew and Jewish culture.

Answer (score 0):

**Should 'Jesus' be called by His Hebrew name Yeshua (ישׁוּעָ), an abbreviated form of 'Yehoshua' in reference to [Exodus 23:21]?**

- Is there a hidden significance to Ivri (Hebrew) names?
- Is God's name removed from Jesus the English translation of **Ἰησοῦς** the Greek mistransliteration of Yeshua (ישׁוּעָ)?

Exodus 23:21 [MT] "Beware of him and obey him; do not rebel against him, for he will not forgive your transgression, for **My NAME** is within him." (הִשָּׁ֧מֶר מִפָּנָ֛יו וּשְׁמַ֥ע בְּקֹל֖וֹ אַל־תַּמֵּ֣ר בּ֑וֹ כִּ֣י לֹ֤א יִשָּׂא֙ לְפִשְׁעֲכֶ֔ם כִּ֥י **שְׁמִ֖י** בְּקִרְבּֽוֹ )

**What is God's NAME?**
In Exodus 3:15 [MT] God specifically states His NAME "YHVH" (**יְהֹוָה**) : "And God said further to Moses, "So shall you say to the children of Israel, '**YHVH** - God of your forefathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you.' This is **My NAME** forever, and this is how I should be mentioned in every generation." (וַיֹּ֩אמֶר֩ ע֨וֹד אֱלֹהִ֜ים אֶל־משֶׁ֗ה כֹּ֣ה תֹאמַר֘ אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל֒ **יְהֹוָ֞ה** אֱלֹהֵ֣י אֲבֹֽתֵיכֶ֗ם אֱלֹהֵ֨י אַבְרָהָ֜ם אֱלֹהֵ֥י יִצְחָ֛ק וֵֽאלֹהֵ֥י יַֽעֲקֹ֖ב שְׁלָחַ֣נִי אֲלֵיכֶ֑ם זֶה־**שְּׁמִ֣י** לְעֹלָ֔ם וְזֶ֥ה זִכְרִ֖י לְדֹ֥ר דֹּֽר)

**Which WORD is The Name YHVH hidden in : "Jesus" or "Yehoshua"?** - His WORD is Salvation "Yeshua".

**Psalm 98:2 [MT]**
"YHVH has made known His Salvation; to the eyes of the nations He has revealed His righteousness." ( **הוֹדִ֣יעַ **יְ֖הֹוָה יְשֽׁוּעָ**ת֑וֹ לְעֵינֵ֥י הַ֜גּוֹיִ֗ם גִּלָּ֥ה צִדְקָתֽוֹ**).

The Hebrew word "Salvation" (**Yeshua, ישׁוּעָ**) from the Tanakh relates to the right-hand of YHVH. King David explicitly states this in Tehillim (Psalms) 18:36 [MT] : "You have given me the shield of **Your Salvation**; Your right hand has supported me" ( וַתִּתֶּן-לִי, מָגֵן **יִשְׁעֶךָ** וִימִינְךָ תִסְעָדֵנִי) ; Psalm 18:35 [KJV] "Thou hast also given me the shield of **Thy Salvation**: and thy right hand hath holden me up".

Our  "Salvation" is called (**Yeshua, ישׁוּעָ**).

Comment: Quotes from the gospel of Luke as to the significance of the name may help this answer.